# How can I make light particles (like feathers) explode then fall down slowly?

Tags: particles, physics

i'm trying to make an animation where a characters head appears suddently in a pile of hay.

The straw particles should almost explode on the top of the pile, then gently fall down.

[image]

I've tested using physics (among others with this tutorial, [wind on leaves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BB_zRvmRnI)), but cannot find a way to make it look good.

I also tested with a cloth (straws would be a texture on this cloth) pushed from below by a ball, but it doesn't look right either.

[image]

I've found something that approaches what I want ([pillow hitting the ground](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=126821896311101)), but this is just a video, there is no explanations.

[image]

Any ideas of how I should handle this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can create your emitter, your particle, and put a *Force Field > Wind* and a *Turbulence* underneath:

[image]

In the *Particle* panel, under *Velocity > Normal* increase the value up to 10 for example to give a bit of dynamic to the particles (if they need to go up instead of everywhere, push up the *Object Align Z* value). Select the *Wind* and in the *Physics* panel, create 2 keyframes on the *Strength*, for example 0 at frame 10, and 8 at frame 20. Give your *Turbulence* a *Stregth* of 20. When the action begins, the particles explode due to their velocity, then they are slowed down by the *Wind*, and agitated by the *Turbulence*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried a simulation without adding Vortexes etc if you have a slow Computer.

[image: Try these settings]

The result should look like this:

[image]